# why happen constant 18446744073709551616 overflows uint64 in this code?

Tags: go, overflow

see code like this:

```
bitSize := 64
maxVal := uint64(1)<<uint(bitSize) - 1
fmt.Println(maxVal) // 18446744073709551615
```

the code has no problem, will print 18446744073709551615

but this will panic, why?

```
fmt.Println(uint64(1)<<uint(64)-1) // constant 18446744073709551616 overflows uint64
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is it a “panic” or “compilation failure”?

Comment: I am sorry , it is "compilation failure", it is not panic, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your first case "works" due to **integer overflow**.

Because you are using `uint(bitSize)`, the expression is no longer a constant and is instead evaluated at runtime.

Breaking it down, this yields:

- `uint64(1)`: that's just `1`
- `1 << 64`: (still a uint64 since `1` is a uint64): 2^64 == 0 in uint64.
- `0 - 1`: 2^64 - 1 (`18446744073709551615`) due to unsigned integer wrap around.

If you change the expression to a constant (by replacing `uint(bitSize)` with `uint(64)`, it will fail at compile time.

---

In the second example, you are asking the compiler to specifically treat `1` as a uint64. It will try to compute the constant `1 << 64` and store it in a uint64, but this is not possible without overflowing.

Instead, you should let the compiler operate on untyped constants and only force the final result to be uint64 (which fits):

```
fmt.Println(uint64(1<<64 - 1))
```

This works because **shifts on untyped integer constants are also untyped integer constants**. The entire constant expression can be evaluated to `2^64 - 1` before trying to store it in a uint64. The [spec on constant expressions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Constant_expressions) has the following to say:

> If the left operand of a constant shift expression is an untyped
> constant, the result is an integer constant; otherwise it is a
> constant of the same type as the left operand, which must be of
> integer type.